# Google Experiments A/B Transaction Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-experiments

I am adding a step into the buying journey on an eCommerce retail website. I want to test to see if this affects overall conversion rates. Our platform doesn't support A/B testing itself so I'm hoping I can test this using Google Experiments.

A lot of examples for Google Experiments involve having a different page/url to test with, so you want to test a different button style or page layout, different content etc. In my case this doesn't apply as my test is a multipage test, if I add a step here how many of those customers end up on my order confirmation page. The business logic which determines whether to add the additional step is handled via javascript so essentially I want half of my visitors to load to old js file and half to load the new js file and then to see how they differ in Google Experiments.

I'm guessing the only way I can do this is to set-up an experiment where the original page would be

www.mydomain.com/product_page

and my variation page would be
www.mydomain.com/product_page?some_variable=1

Then in my framework I could check for that url parameter and load to new js file. But would that track through the whole buying journey once the customer has left that page?

Any help or suggestions would be very welcome.
Thank You
Saul